# Get Left or Right Based on ancenstor for a binary tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary-tree

I have a table that stores a binary tree as follows:

```
Id   ParentId Level Placement 
47   -1       0     0
23   47       1     0
86   47       1     1
5    23       2     0
29   23       2     1
68   86       2     0
8    5        3     1
31   29       3     1
67   68       3     0
.
.
.
```

Using MSSQL
i need sql that given parentId and childId, it tells in refrence to parentId whether its on left or right side. 
For example

FindPoistion(parentId:47,childId: 34 ) returns left

FindPoistion(parentId:23,childId: 8 ) returns left

FindPoistion(parentId:29,childId: 30) returns right

FindPoistion(parentId:47,childId: 5 ) returns left

FindPoistion(parentId:47,childId: 62 ) returns right
FindPoistion(parentId:47,childId: 86 ) returns right

**How do I write an sql that gives me position based on ancenstor?**

Above placement of 0 is left and 1 is right

[image]

this is what i have so far

```
    WITH name_tree
     AS (SELECT Id,
                Parentid,
                 Placement               
         FROM   BinaryTree
         WHERE  Parentid = 47 and Id= 31
         -- this is the starting point you want in your recursion
         UNION ALL
         SELECT c.Id,
                c.Parentid,
                c.Placement

         FROM   BinaryTree c
                JOIN name_tree p
                  ON p.Id = c.ParentId -- this is the recursion
                     AND c.Id <> c.Parentid

                     )
SELECT distinct Id, parentId, Placement 

FROM   name_tree
```

Comment: Seems pretty easy. You have to try something and show us what you've tried.

Comment: This looks like a pretty typical recursive cte. I would suggest that you use NULL as the ParentID when there isn't one instead of -1. Not just from a logical perspective but your code will be a little easier to work with also.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused... If his table has ParentID and Id (Assuming this is Child)... and has Placement to show left or right... Why even use CTE? This would be just straight select statement with parentid/id as parameters, since he said he only needs to know if it's on left or right. Correct me if I'm wrong on my thinking.

Comment: @manderson you need the recursive cte because he wants to know which side of the tree relative to the top level a given node is. For example, node 34 would return LEFT when being compared to 47 but Right when being compared with 23.

Comment: So ... select placement from TABLE where parentid = 47 and id = 34                 select placement from TABLE where parentid = 23 and id = 34

Comment: @SeanLange added sql  so far, but does not work :)

Comment: @manderson your query would return no rows.

Comment: Ok, I'm obviously missing the point. I just assumed all possible values are in his table. The placement for the values are on each record. I assumed he just wanted the placement based on those two inputs.

Comment: He does. Is 34 on the left or right of 47? It should be on the left. But to determine that you have to find the first descendant in the tree relative to the id they want to find. In this case that would be 23. And then you get the placement from that one.

Comment: I understand now. My bad. thanks.

Comment: Are IDs always smaller than parent if on the left and larger than parent if on the right or is that only true for this example?

Comment: @SeanLange Can you take a peek at my new answer?  I think I understand the intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,ParentId  int)
Insert into @YourTable values  (47,-1),(23,47),(86,47),( 5,23),(29,23),(68,86),( 8, 5),(31,29),(67,68),(62,67),(30,31),(34,31),(42,34),(40,42)

Declare @Top    int         = 47 
Declare @Fetch  int         = 31 

;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,ParentId 
            ,Level=1
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  ID=@Fetch
      Union  All
      Select r.ID
            ,r.ParentId 
            ,p.Level+1
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentId  = p.ID)
Select ID = @Top
      ,ParentID = -1
      ,Level = 0
      ,Placement = 0
Union All
Select A.ID
      ,ParentID = case when A.Level=1 then @Top else A.ParentId end
      ,A.Level
      ,Placement = case when A.Level=1 then IIF(A.ID<@Top,0,1) 
                   else case when IsNull(B.ID,A.ParentId) < A.ID then 1 else 0
                   end end
From cteP A
Left  Join cteP B on (A.ParentId=B.ParentId and B.ID<> A.ID)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**While the following Returns**

```
Declare @Top    int         = 47 
Declare @Fetch  int         = 31
```

[image]

Comment: Well done sir!!! I got swamped at work as usual and didn't get a chance to get back here. Meanwhile you posted a totally working solution that nails it exactly as I understand it.